# SimpleTerm title not being set

Tags: plone, vocabulary, z3c.form

I have a form with a `SelectFieldWidget`, that is currently using a static vocabularly, which is basically this:

```py
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary, SimpleTerm

primary_contacts = SimpleVocabulary([
    SimpleTerm( unicode(token), title=unicode(token.upper()), token=token ) for token in [
        'one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten',
    ]
])
```

The vocabulary is assigned to the field in the form schema:

```py
form.widget( primary_contact_person=SelectFieldWidget )
primary_contact_person = schema.List(
    title = u'Nominate Primary Contact',
    required = False,
    value_type = schema.Choice(
        vocabulary=primary_contacts,
    )
)
```

The schema is then serialized using `plone.supermodel` & then deserialized when needed by the form (this is for another requirement).

The form is using a custom, handwritten template, and I'm in the process of adding the `tal` statements to generate the select field options. I had thought I could do this through referencing the widgets on the form, but when I do that I hit a problem:

```
(Pdb) self # break point in form
<Products.Five.metaclass.edit_metadata object at 0xc1ce450>
(Pdb) select = self.widgets['primary_contact_person']
(Pdb) first = [t for t in select.terms][0]
(Pdb) first.token
'one'
(Pdb) first.value
u'one'
(Pdb) first.title
(Pdb)
```

The title is `None` on the term when it's accessed through the widget. I've tried looking it up through the vocabulary:

```
(Pdb) select.terms.getTermByToken('one').title
(Pdb)
```

But again, it's `None`. However, it *is* there for terms in the original vocabulary object:

```
(Pdb) from my.package import primary_contacts
(Pdb) [t for t in primary_contacts][0].title
u'ONE'
```

So while I *could* use the source vocab object directly to provide the values the template needs, the plan is for this vocabulary to eventually be dynamic, at which point I would expect I'd need to interrogate the widget itself.

What am I doing wrong here, why is title not being defined?

Comment: This smells a bug to me... the only way to find out would be probably step debug through all z3c.form and see where the process gets side-tracked with *title*

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem at all, not with defining a `SimpleVocabulary` in the Python prompt like you did. Also, to get the first element of an iterable, just use `next(select.terms)` :-)

Comment: Hah, thanks Martijn, I've no idea why that never occured to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `plone.supermodel`. I should have mentioned more clearly that I'm using the serialized schema to produce the form, and I apologise for this.

Basically, `plone.supermodel` provides an export/import process, which can only deal with simple lists of values.

```
# line 263 in plone.supermodel.exportimport
term = SimpleTerm(token = encoded, value = value, title = value)
```

The solution was to use [named vocabularies](http://dexterity-developer-manual.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/vocabularies.html#named-vocabularies), which serializes the reference to the vocabulary rather than the vocabulary itself.

Sorry again for the lack of information that made this harder to debug.